# how to pass props to styled components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am using styled components and trying to pass props to them.

This is my code:

```
const CustomDiv = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;

  ${props => props.heigth && css`
    top: props.heigth;
  `}
`;
```

The eslint inspector keeps telling me that `top: props.heigth` has a mismatched property value. So, what am I missing here?

Comment: Isn't it `height`?

Comment: @Kinduser it doesn't matters it is just a prop name, sorry, I misstyped it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I believe you mispelled the prop name `heigth -> height`. Secondly, try following solution:

```
const CustomDiv = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;

  ${({ height }) => height && `
    top: ${height}px;
  `}
`;
```

However, if the `height` is equal to `0`, it won't be rendered. You could use either `isNumber`  function from lodash or `typeof height === 'number'`.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I misspelled the prop name... sorry ;) It works.